# Why people are just not serious about my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, asking-questions

When I am have considered [some problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171418/how-to-encrypt-a-file-such-that-the-md5-of-encrypted-file-is-the-password) for days, and come here to see what other people may think. I get full bunch of negative answers and comments!

Are SE sites the best place to ask my questions?

Am I asking in some poor way?

Are people here looking for reputation rather than finding the solution?

Is this evaluation system developing in a wrong way?

I am so sad about this.

Comment: Accusing your readers of being 'stupid' isn't a great way to get help from people, just saying. Also: I've read your question and I *still* don't understand what you're asking. Though I don't work in, or with, security. So that may be expected given my inexperience in those matters.

Comment: Are you looking for a critique of your question?

Comment: Your own attitude is offensive and insulting, which renders this whole discussion pointless to begin with.

Comment: It is not a seriousness problem. Your question is simply not on topic for Stack Overflow. It is not about programming, and there is no code. You don't mention a language that you're using, you don't mention anything you've tried or provide any evidence of the thought you claim to have put into it, and there aren't nearly enough details provided. Worse, the question is poorly-formatted and difficult to understand.

Comment: @DavidThomas I never added 'stupid' until people are just giving no useful information.

Comment: @eccstartup: that happens you should **clarify** your question, not insult people.

Comment: @CodyGray I think encrypt a file is exactly in the area of programming.

Comment: @eccstartup More context is needed, what type of file, in a desktop application? What language? And what have you tried so far

Comment: I am sad you can't hear criticism and won't let people help you by making this into a more proper discussion (referring to Bart effort that you rolled back) now it looks to me like your only goal coming here was whining, not really looking for constructive help.

Comment: Really? You roll that edit back? You're really hoping we'll tell you that you're not the problem, aren't you?

Comment: I'm going to echo @CodyGray here: that question has no place on Stack Overflow. Nor will any variant every have a place on Stack Overflow. On top of that, it appears to be asking for help with a deeply misguided approach to security that makes it as hard as possible to process the initial input and as easy as possible to break the alleged security of the system. Time to step back and rethink.

Comment: I roll back because that edit doesn't tell people what I want to say. @Bart

Comment: And yet here you are @eccstartup. -36 because the question is not all that constructive. But at least you got to say what you wanted to say I guess.

Comment: @eccstartup with the exception of the bit about "do people only care about rep" Bart's edit just applied some paragraphing and grammatical niceties that made your question much easier to read. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 23):

I'm assuming you're looking for a critique of your question. If not I apologise

**Formatting**

- You've put each sentence on in its own paragraph. This makes it
  somewhat difficult to read and will predispose people against you
  before they even read your question

**Content**

- The question is too broad; you are asking us to choose which
  encryption method would be best for you (which is probably too broad)
  without giving enough detail on your problem (which makes it
  impossible to answer).
- There is no context at all, what language
  you're using, what type of application this will apply to.
- You haven't indicated what you've tried already which is a
  requirement of    SO questions

**Specific clarity**

- This sentence "I think the problem is about how to choose the
  password." suggests this question is something about how the end user
  would choose a password whereas this sentence "I want to encrypt it
  in some method(you decide!) with password P into B." suggests its
  about encrypting the password. Possibly with a server. Possible for
  securing something in a standalone application; its unclear which
- This sentence "How can I have md5sum(B) == P?" has no context at all

I think there may be a language barrier which people should always try to see through but at present its not clear what you're asking

Comment: I tried to find a possible answer but failed. If I have no idea of what people are talking about, I will just leave it there. And I suppose not every question is to be answered by every one. Only those who have knowledge in this area can have a say.

Comment: @eccstartup It is true that not every question is on topic on a stack exchange site but with more context this could probably be on topic

Comment: As an aside, @eccstartup, your edit added more bold formatting, and is not an improvement, I feel.

Comment: According to what you say, there must be some questions have nowhere to be placed. @RichardTingle

Comment: @eccstartup Indeed, in fact most (concievable) questions have no place on stack exchange. For example "Which computer should I buy" is off topic across the entire network. I do not believe your question is one of these however. I just think it needs work (to give it context and make it clear)

Comment: So I think SE sites are not fit for me the poor thinkers. I have to found a site myself one day to hold all those crazy idea! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Whatever you say.

Comment: @BoltClock Fruitloops.  I say fruitloops.

Comment: [Funny guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171418/how-to-encrypt-a-file-such-that-the-md5-of-encrypted-file-is-the-password?noredirect=1#comment26624949_18171418), especially after [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192788/why-people-are-just-not-serious-about-my-question#comment602481_192790).

Comment: @AsheeshR Yes, I will do it!