# Downvoting without good reasons?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I want to ask how to tell the difference between downvotes: the question is a bad question(or off popic), and people hate me.

I got downvote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521295/where-does-macports-download-files-from) exactly after I said some improper. I think this is not a good deed, whoever you are. I don't care about reputation, but I want to be treated equally.

Comment: No one can tell the difference, as there is no sure-fire way to know what goes on in people's heads. That said, the downvote wasn't necessarily because people hate you - I'm not 100% sure, but it *looks* like an off-topic question to me

Comment: Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521295/where-does-macports-download-files-from) received **1 downvote**, and you think people hate you?

Comment: (Smiling), then the people made some mistake.

Comment: I don't think people hate you but three out of four of your questions have been downvoted (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1268079/eccstartup). You need to look through and understand why your questions are not suited to SO and either post the questions in the relevant StackExchange or clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: @Pekka웃 As you have said there is no pure off topic. You think it is off topic because you don't know what I am thinking. I think it is not off topic because I do know what I want.

Comment: @keyboardP You didn't see the related topics.

Comment: There are no "related topics"; all posts are evaluated independently. They need to be able to stand on their own.

Comment: @eccstartup - You said "you don't know what I am thinking, ... I do know what I want". We cannot read your mind. It is your job as the poster to give us enough detail to understand your problem.

Comment: @CodyGray They "should", but didn't if you knew who did that.

Comment: @chuex It is true, but has nothing to do with my question. You understand my question, so I am not pure off topic.

Comment: Voting is anonymous. You can't tell who downvoted you and you can't know why since you can't read minds. Period.

Comment: @juergend Of course I know what people think!

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I'm starting to get the feeling that the OP is trolling.

Comment: @vascowhite I am learning, whether from asking question or from getting punished, how to fit for the adults world, struggling from a boy to a man. I am very grateful for you time and patient for you time, chatting with me.

Comment: Oh dear, is this going to be like the next "oscillation?" :P

Comment: Oscillating between a boy and a man @door

Answer (score 12):

> I want to ask how to tell the difference between downvotes: the question is a bad question(or off popic), and people hate me.

Simple: downvotes ***never*** mean that someone hates you.

Votes are applied to *posts* (i.e. content), not people.

Directing votes at *people* would be inappropriate. Our focus is on content here.

That only leaves one possibility: people think that your post is unclear, not useful, off-topic, or otherwise inappropriate. Note that the tooltip on the downvote arrow says something very similar.

Comment: OMG @downvoter Y U HATE ME??!

Comment: That is the intended behaviour but I don't see how you can claim as fact that this is the actual behaviour. The very existence of serial downvote reversal scripts shows that the reality doesn't always live up to this ideal.

Comment: You guys are just making fun of me! @keyboardP

Comment: @eccstartup - You seem to take everything personally http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192788/why-people-are-just-not-serious-about-my-question and then react to people trying to clarify by threatening them with downvotes or calling them stupid. If you really think that people are singling you out then maybe you should delete your account, create a new one with a different name, and post from that. But I highly doubt anyone is purposely downvoting you just because it's you.

Comment: How to delete it? @keyboardP

Comment: Create a new account with the name "keyboardP" and just *watch* the votes roll in, right dawg?

Comment: @eccstartup - You'll have to message a moderator and ask them.

Comment: @CodyGray - If only that worked... :D

Comment: However, @eccstartup, I *do* think that even if all the above is true, (some) people will click through to one's profile after some types of discussion. (Like the discussion you had on Meta today, in which you were not very open to feedback, I feel.) That might have attracted more people to see that unrelated post, which sort of does look off topic to me too. So, that might explain the downvote: not against you as a person, but people *noticed* the post after the earlier discussions.

Comment: Yes, attracting attention to yourself and insulting people tends to...attract attention to yourself. That should not come as a big surprise. People still aren't voting against *you*, though. They're just evaluating your other contributions and deciding that they do not measure up to our standards.

Comment: I am a very serious person, voting every post properly. So I don't think improper votes suitable here. I am not against people but for bad deeds people did. @Arjan

Comment: `downvotes never mean that someone hates you.` SEZ YOU

Comment: I don't know how to contact a moderator, can you help? @keyboardP

Comment: @ecc Use the "flag" link on one of your posts. Select the 'other' reason, and type your message.

Comment: @eccstartup protip: if you worry and complain about the occasional downvote, you're going to have a bad time. Just leave it be, and don't take them so seriously.  Everyone will receive downvotes from time to time. There is no point in contacting a moderator over this: there is nothing they will be able to do.

Comment: @CodyGray I won't do such things like make a profile of others. It is no fun.

Comment: @eccstartup, why do you insist it's an *improper vote*? People can vote how they want. Like *if* one feels a question about MacPorts doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, then they might vote to close if they can, or just downvote if they can't vote to close. You drew the attention to your posts.

Comment: Eh, I'm pretty sure there are a few people who consistently downvote my content or hold it to a higher standard (and I'm sure this is not unique to me). But when you post a lot and are involved in meta/discussions about a beta site, you are bound to find someone who *really* disagrees with you. But I'm also 99.99% sure that's not the case for this question.

Comment: @enderland Just because someone tends to disagree with your views doesn't mean that they're singling you out as a person and downvoting because of that. Especially on a Meta site. I won't name names, but there are a handful of people I find myself disagreeing with more often than not. I downvote their posts frequently, but it's nothing personal. Then there are others I agree with 99% of the time. It might seem like I'm upvoting just because of who the author is, but that's merely coincidental. I doubt anyone is voting down your content on the main site just out of spite.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not talking about the main site but a beta site.